# Открытие ссылки в одном экземпляре

Tags: html, javascript

Когда мы делаем вот так:

```
<a href=javascript: onClick=win1=window.open('','','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return true;>
```

то открыватся ссылка в одном экземпляре, то есть когда мы тыкаем еще раз на ссылку, то новое окно не открывается, но открывшее окно обновляется! Вопрос, есть ли еще методы, чтобы так сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href=javascript: onClick=win1=window.open('','','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes','_blank');return true;>
```